# How would religion be affected if two nations who worshipped the same gods went into war?

Tags: warfare, politics, religion, belief

So my world has two nations who are at a constant war for land and resources, destroying the landscape all around their always changing frontier. But this war is just a secondary plot which drives the main premise of humans neglecting and destroying nature through their path.

In my world, spirits and nature are the same, and the people worship this spirits as Gods, loving them as much as they fear them: overharvesting and the destruction of nature angers the spirits, who in turn wreak havoc to both armies. But the claims to land and the power-race are ultimately stronger than morals.

Would it be reasonable for both nations to share the same religion without it breaking apart? Could religion be left in the background while the nations fight each other? What if said religion was strongly tied with the government in both nations?

Comment: So... the Greeks and the Trojans? The Romans and the Greeks?

Comment: @LoganR.I think the premise of the OP's question is that god in this world indisputably real with tangible and immediate effect. More akin to two children fighting and messing up their parents' house in the process.

Comment: It's not that the query is broad: it's more like "have you done any basic research"? I mean, religion has been used as either true or false pretext for fighting wars pretty much for ever and often between related peoples (ancient Greece was a hotbed of same god worshipping warriors). Also, your query lacks some detail: are the gods "real" (physical entities existing in the world) or figments of people's imagination? What áre the consequences of neglecting Nature, and who will enforce them? Check out the [tour] and [help] for more on question improvement. But great question foundation here!!

Comment: So nearly all European wars after rome.

Comment: One prime example : [The Hundred Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years'_War).  At that time all of Europe believed in exactly the same religion and basically everyone believed in that religion fervently.  Still managed to have 116 years of war across multiple generations and involving practically every nation with even the vaguest excuse to get involved so they could claim a piece of the action.

Comment: It should be fine if the god is in charge of hell ;D

Comment: @DKNguyen And works like the Illiad, the Odyssey, and the Aeniad treat their gods as indisputably real with tangible and immediate effects. The fact that we don't believe that they were is irrelevant--the question was clearly contemplated by the composers of these tales.

Comment: @elemtilas OP does say that the gods in their story are real - "In my world nature fights back, as spirits are angered by war and overharvesting of resources".

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Don't forget the Romans and the Carthaginians.

Comment: @TheDaleks I don't think they had the same gods. The Carthaginians were semitic, after all.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: The Roman religion and the Greek religion were profoundly different. What happened is that the Romans had this unofficial policy of pretending that foreign gods were just different names for the good old Roman gods. Eventually poets, painters etc. began using Greek mythology as a stand in for the non-existent Roman mythology ($\leftarrow$ Roman gods being abstract entities, they could not have adventures in human-land); but the official religion, the official priests and so on never confused Venus with Aphrodite or Mars with Ares.

Comment: @AlexP I know, but the question isn't about having the same religion, it's about worshipping the same gods. And having a systematic identification of foreign names for gods with your names for gods, even if it isn't "official", seems to fulfill that criterion for me.

Comment: Catholic vs protestant comes to mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably not a detriment to war - perhaps even the opposite**

In the real world, having the same religion has never been a detriment to war. Just look at all the wars in Europe through Christian times. Sure, some of them have been between countries with different branches of Christianity (Catholic vs. Protestant), but there have e.g. been many wars between Denmark and Sweden (both protestant) and between the nations that now make up Italy (all Catholic). In general, the churches have considered war a secular matter they shouldn't get involved in (except when fighting heathens and infidels), though this hasn't prevented them from blessing cannons and supplying field priests. Similarly, in ancient times, having the same gods didn't prevent Greek city states from waging war on each other, and there were several civil wars in Egypt.

Now, we could argue that none of these gods were real, but most people probably believed they were, and this didn't prevent them from going to war. Assuming that gods are real in your world (which isn't clear from your question), whether this would prevent war depends on the nature of the gods and their religions. Some nations or tribes may wage war to prove that they are the most beloved of the gods, and some gods may advocate war as a way to test or strenghten their followers - or gods may use nations as game pieces in idle war games or let nations go to war to be able to wager on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

***Picking Favorites:***

If you have two sides in a war, both with the same real, interventionist gods, they would obviously be competing for the favor of those gods if it is in their interests. Your gods love nature/are nature/are powered by nature. If one side was exploiting resources and the other wasn't, the gods should intervene on the "faithful" side. Religious people on the exploiter side would rise up against the government as it became clear they were in the wrong.

How important this is depends entirely on how faithful the people are. A very faithful people will "go with gods" and NOT exploit. a "gods-less" people will ignore the gods if the benefits of exploitation outweighed the harm from the opposition of the gods. An "anti-gods" people that disliked their gods would actively seek to destroy the nature that is the source of the god's power.

You could mix this up, and have gods favoring particular aspects of nature. Oak tree gods might be fine with people switching to making tools from ash trees, but then you'll anger the ash gods. River gods might love their followers sailing on their waters, while forest gods hate trees cut down to make ships. How unified are your gods?

Comment: Which is exactly one of the drivers of the plot in the *Iliad* and the *Odyssey*. Aphrodite and Poseidon favored the Trojans (and had Achilles of their shit list), Athena favored the Greeks (and she clearly had a soft spot for Ulysses).